# sed only print substring in a string

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I am trying to get a substring in a string that is in a large line of data. 
 The regex (INC............) matches  the substring I am trying to get the value of at https://regexr.com/, but I am unable to get the value of the substring into a variable or print it out.

The part of the string around this value is

```
......TemplateID2":null,"Incident Number":"INC000006743193","Priority":"High","mc_ueid":null,"Assint......
```

I am getting the error  char 26: unknown option to `s' when I try this or the entire string is printed out.

```
cat /tmp/file1 | sed -n  's/\(INC............\)/\1/p'

cat /tmp/file1 | sed -n 's/./*\(INC............).*/\1/'
```

Comment: Is your data JSON? If so, use jq or something else that can parse JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Using sed, you need to remove what precedes and follows the string:

```
 sed 's/.*\(INC............\).*/\1/' file
```

But you can also use `grep`, if your implementation supports the `-o` option:

```
grep -o 'INC............' file
```

Perl can be used, too:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /(INC............)/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like JSON. If it's got `{braces}` around it which you cut out before posting (tsk tsk), you should definitely use `jq` if it's available. That said, this page needs some awk!

POSIX (works everywhere):

```
awk 'match($0, /INC[^"]+/) {print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' /tmp/file1`
```

GNU (works on GNU/Linux):

```
gawk 'match($0, /INC[^"]+/, a) {print a[0]}' /tmp/file1
```

If you have more than one match per line (GNU):

```
gawk '{while(match($0=substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH), /INC[0-9]+/, a)) print a[0]}' /tmp/file1
```